# How do I get the average number of occurrences of a date for each day of the week in excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Let's say I have an excel spreadsheet recording some event that reoccurs often multiple times a day, sometimes not at all in a day. So I record the date and a bunch of other information for the event every time it happens. What I'm trying to find is, the average number of times this event occurs on each day of the week.

[list of dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9b32.png)

So I want it to look at each day of the week, and find the average number of dates matching each day of the week, starting at the first date and ending at the last date. It should also take into account missing dates, so if there's a Friday with no records, that should affect the average occurrences for Friday.

I've tried using a Pivot Table to find this, and it can get me most of the way there, but it doesn't know to include missing dates within the "count of date" column.

[pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx8zB.png)

I'm not trying to find the average of some other value per day of the week, just the average occurrences of a date per the day of the week. Is this something that is possible in excel, or will I need to use scripts?

For an example where there's [multiple weeks of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSZms.png), I would expect to get a table of results like this:

| Day of the week | Average |
| --- | --- |
| Mon | 2.50 |
| Tue | 2.00 |
| Wed | 2.50 |
| Thu | 2.50 |
| Fri | 1.00 |
| Sat | 2.50 |
| Sun | 2.50 |

With Friday being lower as there is no Friday date in the provided range (the first Friday has 2 records, and the second Friday has 0 records).

Comment: would you provide the expected output for your sample data, it is not clear to me how do you want to do an average since. you have dates. Please provide your data in table markdown format. You can use the following [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#)

Comment: I've updated my post to include my expected output. My expected solution would be to check each possible date from the first date to the last date, and see how many records for that date exist, and then getting the day of the week (by the second column or otherwise) for that date to put that count towards the average for that day of the week. If this is out of the scope of excel, I can try finding doing it with python instead.

Comment: Thanks, check my answer, based on my understanding of what are you looking for. The suggestion to put data in table markdown format is mainly for the **input**. It allows to copy it to excel. It is less relevant for the output. Since you didn't provide the input in table markdown format, I tested with a smaller dataset, so the output won't be the same. Please check it with your real data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We would need more data to really verify it (try it and let me know). You can use the following formula in cell `D1`:

```
=LET(A, A1:A14, B, B1:B14, wdays, TEXT(SEQUENCE(7), "ddd"),
 cnts, COUNTIFS(B, wdays, A, TOROW(UNIQUE(A))),
 ones, SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(cnts),,1,0), totals, MMULT(N(cnts>0), ones),
 sum, MMULT(cnts, ones), HSTACK(wdays, IFERROR(sum/totals,"")))
```

Or you can use a more succinct formula via `BYROW` as follows:

```
=LET(A, A1:A14, B, B1:B14, wdays, TEXT(SEQUENCE(7), "ddd"),
 cnts, COUNTIFS(B, wdays, A, TOROW(UNIQUE(A))),
 HSTACK(wdays, BYROW(cnts, LAMBDA(x, IFERROR(AVERAGE(IF(x=0,"", x)),"")))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

**Note**: If you want the result presented starting from Monday, then define `wdays` as follow: `TEXT(SEQUENCE(7,,2),"ddd")`.

The name `cnts`, has the counts per week days (rows) and per columns (unique dates from column **A**). The rest is just to do the match to calculate the average. We ignore dates with no counts for calculating the average, as per my understanding of the sample input data from the question.